# easiest way to capture streaming media with video and sound

Tags: wireless

I would like to recorded videos with sound. The windows had a free software called Freecorder was looking for something simular
.

Answer (score 1):

[RecordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php)

```
sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop
```